# Call KernelInterface in Symfony Controller

Tags: php, symfony

I need to run some Symfony commands from controller in order server are not support ssh connection.

I found this Symfony docs
https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/console/command_in_controller.html

```
/**
 * @Route("/command/run")
 * @Method("POST")
 *
 * @param KernelInterface $kernel
 *
 * @return Response
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function runCommandAction(KernelInterface $kernel)
{
    $application = new Application($kernel);
    $application->setAutoExit(false);

    $input = new ArrayInput([
        'command' => 'doctrine:schema:update',
        "--force" => true
    ]);

    $output = new BufferedOutput();
    $application->run($input, $output);

    $content = $output->fetch();

    return new Response($content);
}
```

This code is almost like an example from Symfony docs.

But I get this error when the code is run.

**The provided type "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface" is an
interface, and can not be instantiated**

Symfony version is 3.3
PHP version is 7.1

I must add that I am using FOSRest bundle, but I guess that should not be a problem.

What I do wrong here? 
Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you will need to create an alias in your services.yaml file. https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#working-with-interfaces This is sort of a recent change to autowire.

Comment: I tried your code on a fresh S4.0 project and it worked as expected.  I think you must have two services implementing KernelInterface or maybe your vendor needs updating.  In any event, try adding Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface: '@kernel' to your service file.

Comment: @Cerad thanks :) I will notify you if this works to add answer wich I will make as helpful one :) You can add even now if you want.

Comment: @StevanTosic  Looks like FOSRestBundle is trying to convert your argument, there is an open issue: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/1758

Comment: @Orange18947 I just found working solution, can you check it?

Comment: @Cerad It was FOSRest related issue, unfortunately.

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had solved this issue by adding interface in construct class.

```
/**
 * @var KernelInterface
 */
private $kernel;

public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel)
{
    $this->kernel = $kernel;
}

/**
 * @Route("/command/run")
 * @Method("POST")
 *
 * @param KernelInterface $kernel
 *
 * @return Response
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function runCommandAction()
{
    $application = new Application($this->kernel);
    $application->setAutoExit(false);

    $input = new ArrayInput([
        'command' => 'doctrine:schema:update',
        "--force" => true
    ]);

    $output = new BufferedOutput();
    $application->run($input, $output);

    $content = $output->fetch();

    return new Response($content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to get the kernel in a controller is like this.

```
$this->get('kernel')
```

So instead of adding the kernel to the controller object as a private member variable like this.

```
$application = new Application($this->kernel);
```

I do this.

```
$application = new Application($this->get('kernel'));
```

I'm still running 3.4 at this time.